# How to replace a string with another with interleaving characters in R

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse

I have the following strings:

```
x  <- "??????????DRHRTRHLAK??????????"
x2 <- "????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH"
x3 <- "FKDHKHIDVK????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH"
x4 <- "FKDHKHIDVK????????????????????"
```

What I want to do is to replace all the `?` characters with
another string

```
rep <- "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv"
```

Resulting in:

```
ndqeegillkDRHRTRHLAKkkkfpssyvv           # x
ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvvTRCYHIDPHH           # x2
FKDHKHIDVKndqeegillkkkkfpssyvvTRCYHIDPHH # x3
FKDHKHIDVKndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv           # x4
```

Basically, keeping the order of `rep` in the replacement with the interleaving characters `DRHRTRHLAK` in `x`.

The total length of `rep` is the same as the total length of `?`, 20 characters.

Note that I don't want to split `rep` manually again as an extra step.

I tried this but failed:

```
>gsub(pattern = "\\?+", replacement = rep, x = x)
[1] "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvvDRHRTRHLAKndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example data:

```
x <- c(
    "??????????DRHRTRHLAK??????????",
    "????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH",
    "FKDHKHIDVK????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH"
)
rep <- "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv"
```

Fix it up with `regmatches<-` replacements in a vectorised fashion:

```
gr <- gregexpr("\\?+", x)
csml <- lapply(gr, \(x) cumsum(attr(x, "match.length")) )
regmatches(x, gr) <- lapply(csml, \(x) substring(rep, c(1,x[-length(x)]+1), x))
#[1] "ndqeegillkDRHRTRHLAKkkkfpssyvv"          
#[2] "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvvTRCYHIDPHH"          
#[3] "FKDHKHIDVKndqeegillkkkkfpssyvvTRCYHIDPHH"
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get this error ``Error: unexpected input in "csml <- lapply(gr, \``

Comment: @littleworth - just tried it again in a fresh session and it works. If you are using an older version of R try `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`

Comment: `function(x)` works. Thanks a million!

Comment: I tried this  `x <-  "K?ED??HRDDKDKD?HE?REKE??DE?KKK"` and `rep <- "rhhhhitv"`. But failed. It should give `KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDEvKKK`.
But it give this instead: `KrEDrhhHRDDKDKDrhhhHErhhhhREKErhhhhitDErhhhhitvKKK`. How can I modify it?

Comment: @littleworth - see my modifications. There was a small issue with the substringing

Answer (score 1):

String Split with `substr()`:

```
x <- "??????????DRHRTRHLAK??????????"
rep <- "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv"
x<-gsub(pattern = "^\\?+", replacement = substr(rep, 1, 10), x = x)
x<-gsub(pattern = "\\?+$", replacement = substr(rep, 11, 20), x = x)
x
#[1] "ndqeegillkDRHRTRHLAKkkkfpssyvv"
```

Regex `^` matches start, and `$` matches end.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to split `rep` manually again as an extra step.

Comment: What about an automatic split?

Comment: I updated my OP for a more general example.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of ?'s and then cut `rep` based on that:

```
x <- "??????????DRHRTRHLAK??????????"
rep <- "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv"

pattern <- "(\\?+)(DRHRTRHLAK)(\\?+)"
n <- nchar(gsub(pattern, "\\1", x))

gsub(pattern, paste0(substr(rep, 1, n), "\\2", substr(rep, n+1, nchar(rep))), x)
#[1] "ndqeegillk??????????kkkfpssyvv"
```

### Edit: new examples:

A very verbose way is to do a if else chain, checking where the ?'s are, and substituting `rep` accordingly.

```
if(grepl("^\\?.+\\?$", x)){ #?'s on both ends
  n <- gsub(pattern, "\\1", x) %>% nchar()
  gsub(pattern, paste0(substr(rep, 1, n), "\\2", substr(rep, n+1, nchar(rep))), x)
} else if(grepl("^\\?", x)){ #?'s only on start
  n <- gsub(pattern, "\\1", x) %>% nchar()
  gsub(pattern, paste0(substr(rep, 1, n), "\\2"), x)
} else if(grepl("\\?$", x)){ #?'s only on end
  n <- gsub(pattern, "\\2", x) %>% nchar()
  gsub(pattern, paste0("\\2", substr(rep, 1, n)), x)
} else if(grepl("^[A-Z]+\\?+[A-Z]+$", x)){ #?'s only on middle
  n <- gsub(pattern, "\\2", x) %>% nchar()
  gsub("([A-Z]+)\\?+([A-Z]+)", paste0("\\1", substr(rep, 1, n), "\\2"), x)
}
```

Comment: Nice! You mean "\\2" though

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to generically convert string like `"??????????DRHRTRHLAK??????????"` to the pattern `"(\\?+)(DRHRTRHLAK)(\\?+)"`. For example other string like: `"??????????DRHRTRHLAKTRCYHIDPHH"` or `FKDHKHIDVK??????????TRCYHIDPHH`

Comment: I updated my OP for more examples.

Comment: Thanks, but your updated code doesn't work. Please give an example result of testing on your side.