# How to replace a character in a string with characters in a vector by preserving its order using R

Tags: r, string, replace

I have this string:

```
 seed_pattern <- "K?ED??HRDDKDKD?HE?REKE??DE?KKK"
```

given another string

```
bb_seq <- "rhhhhitv"
```

What I'd like to do is to replace `?` with a character in `bb_seq` by keeping the order of `bb_seq` resulting in :

The total length of `?` is guaranteed to be the same with `bb_seq`.

```
KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDEvKKK
```

How can I achieve that with R?

I tried this but failed:

```
  seed_pattern <- "K?ED??HRDDKDKD?HE?REKE??DE?KKK"
  bb_seq <- "rhhhhitv"
  sp <- seed_pattern
  gr   <- gregexpr("\\?+", sp)
  csml <- lapply(gr, function(sp) cumsum(attr(sp, "match.length")))
  regmatches(sp, gr) <- lapply(csml, function(sp) substring(bb_seq, c(1, sp[1]), sp))
  sp

  # KrEDrhhHRDDKDKDrhhhHErhhhhREKErhhhhitDErhhhhitvKKK
```

I'm open to non-regex solutions.

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all()` is vectorized over it's arguments but isn't doing this how I expected. I tried `str_replace_all(seed_pattern, "\\?+", unlist(str_split(bb_seq, "")))`.

Comment: You can do this in a one-liner: `regmatches(seed_pattern, gregexpr("\\?", seed_pattern)) <- strsplit(bb_seq, "")`

Comment: Awesome! Put that in an answer, I'd upvote it!

Comment: @RitchieSacramento - that's genius - almost certainly beats my (was broken, now fixed) answer to the previous question using regmatches - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74397119/how-to-replace-a-string-with-another-with-interleaving-characters-in-r/74397370 - I suspect it would be just as efficient too.

Comment: @littleworth if any of the posted answers solved your problem you may want to accept one and hence your question would be solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in a one-liner with a slight change to the solution you received from your earlier question (thanks @thelatemail):

```
regmatches(seed_pattern, gregexpr("\\?", seed_pattern)) <- strsplit(bb_seq, "")
```

Check it provides the expected result:

```
seed_pattern == "KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDEvKKK"
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

Split, replace, combine:

```
> target <- strsplit(seed_pattern, "")[[1]]
> replacement <- strsplit(bb_seq, "")[[1]]
> target[target=="?"] <- replacement
> paste(target, collapse = "")
[1] "KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDEvKKK"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `regmatches` approach is the best, but here's a sequential one-liner if you like to see your solution grow step by step:

```
sapply(strsplit(bb_seq, "")[[1]], function(char) seed_pattern <<- sub("\\?", char, seed_pattern))
                               r 
"KrED??HRDDKDKD?HE?REKE??DE?KKK" 
                               h 
"KrEDh?HRDDKDKD?HE?REKE??DE?KKK" 
                               h 
"KrEDhhHRDDKDKD?HE?REKE??DE?KKK" 
                               h 
"KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHE?REKE??DE?KKK" 
                               h 
"KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKE??DE?KKK" 
                               i 
"KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEi?DE?KKK" 
                               t 
"KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDE?KKK" 
                               v 
"KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDEvKKK"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (perhaps not very efficiently) by replacing one `?` at a time:

```r
seed_pattern <- "K?ED??HRDDKDKD?HE?REKE??DE?KKK"
bb_seq <- "rhhhhitv"

for (ch in unlist(strsplit(bb_seq, ""))) {
  print(ch)
  seed_pattern <- sub("?", ch, seed_pattern, fixed = TRUE)
}

print(seed_pattern)
# [1] "KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDEvKKK"
```

Sadly `sub` is not vectorized over the `replacement` argument!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a long way. I can't still do these things without thinking in tibbles or data frames . Hoping that someday I will grasp this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(seed_pattern, bb_seq) %>% 
  separate_rows(seed_pattern, sep='\\?') %>% 
  mutate(seed_pattern = paste(paste0(seed_pattern, substr(bb_seq, row_number(), row_number())), collapse = "")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pull(seed_pattern)
```

```
[1] "KrEDhhHRDDKDKDhHEhREKEitDEvKKK"
```